# Error al correr "bundle install" ruby on rail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

tengo una situación al momento de correr el bundle install y manda un mensaje:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _SSL_library_init
  Referenced from: /Users/adair/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle
  Expected in: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _SSL_library_init
  Referenced from: /Users/adair/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle
  Expected in: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
```

he estado verificando pero todo lo que encuentro es que los directorios tienen un error.
si alguien tiene alguna idea de lo que sucedió, apreciaria su apoyo.

Answer (score 0):

Creo haber tenido un problema similar en el pasado con una actualización de osx y mi manera de arreglarlo fue un poco agresiva, pero efectiva, que fue reinstalar openssl/rbenv/ruby. En caso que uses homebrew, puedes probar con:

```
brew reinstall openssl
brew upgrade ruby-build rbenv
rbenv install 2.6.1
```